# Replace several consecutive lines with a single line using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, replace

In all my python scripts, I'd like to replace the 2 consecutive lines

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)
```

with just the line

```
plt.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)
```

So far, I've found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16123210/12298276) to replace 2 consecutive lines with an expression applied to each of these lines, but not how to replace the 2 lines with a single line altogether. Regarding my unsuccessful approach it applied the following sed-string:

```
sed '/import matplotlib as mpl$/N;//s/mpl.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)/plt.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)/g'
```

**Note** that the first line (`import matplotlib as mpl`) can also occur at other places in the file **and should be left unchanged there**, so the goal is to perform a replacement only if both lines are found one following the other in the order given.

**EDIT on additional scope involving `find`:**

The ultimate goal is to replace these 2 lines in several textfiles found via the `find` - command using a pipeline similar to the following manner:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -exec sed 'old-lines/s/single-new-line' {} \;
```

---

**System-specifics:**

OS: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To edit a file, use a scriptable text editor, such as [Ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) or [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) (both POSIX editors).
The syntax is very similar.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/d' 's/mpl/plt' 'w' 'q' | ed -s file
```

```
printf '%s\n' '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/d' 's/mpl/plt' 'x' | ex file
```

- `printf '%s\n'` supplies commands to the editor.
- `/^import matplotlib as mpl$/d` deletes the first line matching the pattern.
- `s/mpl/plt` performs the substitution on the next line.
- `w` and `q` or `x` save the changes.

If you really want Sed,

```
sed '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/N; s/.*\nmpl/plt/' file
```

---

Addressing your expanded question:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -exec sh -c '
    printf "%s\n" "/^import matplotlib as mpl\$/d" "s/mpl/plt" "w" "q" |
    ed -s "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: How can I implement this in a pipeline starting with `find`, such as e.g.: `find /path/to/dir/ -type f -exec printf '%s\n' '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/d' 's/mpl/plt' 'x' | ex file {} \;`

Comment: @AndreasL. If you have another question, please consider opening another question.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I edited my initial question so that everything is included. I hope this can be answered here as well, that everything stays in the same thread. Basically, Quasimodo just needs to extend his answer.

Comment: @Quasimodo, is there a reason why `Ex` and `Ed` are preferred by you over `sed`?

Comment: @AndreasL. In this case, it is because the second substitution will happen on the line below the original `import` line. With `sed`, it would be ever so slightly more tricky (but not much) to do the same sort of operation (delete a line and change the one after it).

Comment: @Kusalananda, alright, thanks for the explanation. So, is there a possibility to pipe files resulting from `find` with one of the `printf ... | ex ...` - solutions?

Comment: @AndreasL. `find ... -exec sh -c 'printf "..." "..." ... | ed -s "$1"' sh {} \;`

Comment: @Kusalanda, great, thanks!

Comment: @AndreasL. See also updated answer.

Comment: `find /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -not -path "*.history*" -not -path '*__pycache__*' -type f -exec sed -i -e '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/N; s/.*\nmpl/plt/' {} \;` worked like a charm.

Comment: The command I built based on @Kusalananda's instructions didn't even start executing, probably due to a wrong implementation from my part: `find /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -not -path "*.history*" -not -path '*__pycache__*' -type f -exec sh -c "printf '%s\n' '/^import matplotlib as mpl$/d' 's/mpl/plt' 'x'" | ed -s "$1"' sh {} \;`

Comment: @AndreasL. Have a look at the last part of the answer that I added. Pay attention to the types of quotes use and how `$` is escaped in the `sed` expression.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't have to be `sed`, you can use `awk` for the task:

```
awk '$0=="import matplotlib as mpl" {buf=$0; next}
     buf {if (/^mpl\.style\.use/) {sub(/^mpl/,"plt")} else {print buf}; buf=""} 1' inputfile
```

- When a line exactly reading `import matplotlib as mpl` is encountered, it will store it in a buffer `buf` and skip execution to the next line.
- If the buffer variable is set, and the current line starts with `mpl.style.use`, it will replace that part of the current line with `plt.style.use` and discard the buffer content.
- If the buffer variable is set, but the current line does not match the "second line" pattern, it will print the buffer content before printing the current line. The buffer is then cleared afterwards.
- For all lines encountered while the buffer is empty, we simply print the line as is.

If you require a more exact match of the second line, change the second rule to

```
buf {if ($0=="mpl.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)" {sub(/^mpl/,"plt")} else {print buf}; buf=""}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. However, when I tried the following command, it showed an endless output stream (probably going through all files) which wasn't even finished after 20 minutes, so I stopped it: `find /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -not -path "*.history*" -not -path '*__pycache__*' -type f  -exec awk '$0=="import matplotlib as mpl" {buf=$0; next} buf {if (/^mpl\.style\.use/) {sub(/^mpl/,"plt")} else {print buf}; buf=""} 1' {} \;`